# "Refused to split GroupingShuffleReader" when downscaling workers pool

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I'll briefly describe dataflow job to have more context:

Transform 1:

```
return input
    .apply(Create.of(fileOrPattern))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new ResolveFilePatternFn()).named("ResolveFilePattern"))
    .apply("GroupByResolvedPaths", GroupByKey.create())
    .apply("ValuesResolvedPaths", Values.create())
    .apply("FlattenResolvedPaths", Flatten.iterables())
    .apply(ParDo.of(new UnzipAndLoadFn()).named("UnzipAndLoad"));
```

Transform 2:

```
input
    .apply(ParDo.of(new ProcessContent()).named("ProcessContent"))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new StoreData()).named("StoreData"));

return PDone.in(input.getPipeline());
```

The GroupByKey+Values+Flatten added as a preventing fusion optimization. It proved that job is actually running faster with this piece of logic implemented.

Job started with `--maxNumWorkers=5`. Everything worked OK until worker pool downsizing:

> Autoscaling: Resized worker pool from 5 to 3

The job simply blocks, it's "running" but nothing happens, no progress, nothing. Worker keeps logging:

> Refused to split GroupingShuffleReader unstarted in shuffle range [ShufflePosition(base64:AAAAAg), ShufflePosition(base64:AAAAAw)) at AAAAAoAAAQ

NOTE: When I start the same job with `--maxNumWorkers=1` everything works as expected.

Any thoughts about the pipeline construction and what could cause this kind of behavior ?

UPDATE: UnzipAndLoad PTransform code

```
public final class UnzipAndLoad extends PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<KV<String, String>>> {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UnzipAndLoad.class);

  private final String fileOrPattern;

  private UnzipAndLoad(final String fileOrPattern) {
    super("UnzipAndLoad");

    Preconditions.checkNotNull(fileOrPattern, "file pattern must not be null");
    Preconditions.checkArgument(StringUtils.isNotBlank(fileOrPattern), "file pattern must not be empty");

    this.fileOrPattern = fileOrPattern;
  }

  public static UnzipAndLoad from(final String fileOrPattern) {
    return new UnzipAndLoad(fileOrPattern);
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(final PBegin input) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(fileOrPattern, "file pattern must not be null");
    Preconditions.checkArgument(StringUtils.isNotBlank(fileOrPattern), "file pattern must not be empty");
  }

  @Override
  public PCollection<KV<String, String>> apply(final PBegin input) {
    /*
     * This composite transform involves the following steps:
     *   1. Create input from fileOrPattern String
     *
     *   2. Resolve fileOrPattern string to valid existing paths using dataflow's IOChannelUtils.
     *
     *   3. Read resolved path(s), unzip them, read files from archive(s), load XML files content
     *   into String and produce pairs of path + content.
     */
    return input
        .apply(Create.of(fileOrPattern))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new ResolveFilePatternFn()).named("ResolveFilePattern"))
        .apply("GroupByResolvedPaths", GroupByKey.create())
        .apply("ValuesResolvedPaths", Values.create())
        .apply("FlattenResolvedPaths", Flatten.iterables())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new UnzipAndLoadFn()).named("UnzipAndLoadPerSource"));
  }

  @Override
  public void populateDisplayData(final DisplayData.Builder builder) {
    super.populateDisplayData(builder);
    builder.addIfNotNull(DisplayData.item("fileOrPattern", fileOrPattern).withLabel("File Pattern"));
  }

  @VisibleForTesting
  static class ResolveFilePatternFn extends DoFn<String, KV<Integer, String>> {
    @Override
    public void processElement(final ProcessContext context) throws Exception {
      final String fileOrPattern = context.element();
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(fileOrPattern, "file pattern must not be null");
      Preconditions.checkState(StringUtils.isNotBlank(fileOrPattern), "file pattern must not be empty");

      // using dataflow i/o utils to handle globs, eg
      // /user/xxx/yyy/*.txt -> can resolve to 2 files:
      //   - /user/xxx/yyy/first.txt
      //   - /user/xxx/yyy/second.txt
      final AtomicInteger key = new AtomicInteger(0);
      IOChannelUtils.getFactory(fileOrPattern).match(fileOrPattern).forEach(file -> {
        context.output(KV.of(key.getAndIncrement(), file));
      });
    }
  }

  @VisibleForTesting
  static class UnzipAndLoadFn extends DoFn<String, KV<String, String>> {
    private static final Pattern PATH_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("(.+)/(.+)[.]xml", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    @VisibleForTesting
    final Aggregator<Long, Long> matchedFiles = createAggregator("Matched Files", new Sum.SumLongFn());

    @VisibleForTesting
    final Aggregator<Long, Long> unmatchedFiles = createAggregator("Unmatched Files", new Sum.SumLongFn());

    @Override
    public void processElement(final ProcessContext context) throws Exception {
      final String inputPath = context.element();
      Preconditions.checkNotNull(inputPath, "input path must not be null");
      Preconditions.checkState(StringUtils.isNotBlank(inputPath), "input path must not be empty");

      // let dataflow utils decide if this is the file path or gcs path
      try (final ReadableByteChannel channel = IOChannelUtils.getFactory(inputPath).open(inputPath);
           final ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(channel))) {
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
          if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            final String path = entry.getName();

            final Matcher matcher = PATH_PATTERN.matcher(path);
            if (matcher.find()) {
              final String content = IOUtils.toString(new BOMInputStream(stream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
              matchedFiles.addValue(1L);
              context.output(KV.of(path, content));
            } else {
              unmatchedFiles.addValue(1L);
              log.debug("Ignoring unmatched file: '{}'.", path);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the job ID? In general, a job ID is always necessary for debugging problems like this one.

Comment: Job is in private project, can't grant you access. Is there any other info I could provide ? Something particular ? Thanks

Comment: Note that I'm not asking for access to the project - I'm just asking for the job ID, which looks like e.g. 2016-11-18_xx_xx_xx-............. . The job ID contains no information per se and it's safe to post it publicly, but since I'm an on-call engineer on Cloud Dataflow, I'll be able to access information specific to Cloud Dataflow (i.e. the specification of the pipeline and an overview of how it was executed, but not the data processed by it unless the data is embedded in the pipeline).

Comment: The message you're seeing per se is harmless and can appear in normal pipelines, though if you're seeing a lot of it, that's worrying. Maybe it would help if you can get the stacktrace on the worker processes on VMs?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This one is most recent: 2016-11-25_11_50_55-8791912326263415932 and yes I'm seeing those messages a lot.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong in that job - it appears to be progressing well, albeit slowly (being blocked in UnzipAndLoadFn most likely), but the whole job runs for less than 10 minutes - what is the performance you're expecting / how are you concluding that it's making no progress?

Comment: I actually stopped it, since I've experienced this before and there's no point waiting it to finish. Two more similar examples: 2016-11-18_05_25_07-5631171825003433545 and 2016-11-18_05_24_43-6271887801687982451. Thank you.

Comment: Also, here's the one that finished successfully after running with maxWorkers=1, 2016-11-25_12_06_22-6882569910894492567, same input as 2016-11-25_11_50_55-8791912326263415932.

Comment: It seems, again, that the slow jobs are blocked in UnzipAndLoadFn. You may want to add some logging to better debug (using Worker Logs) what's happening inside that function. Does the pipeline always run fine with Direct Runner?

Comment: The "refusing to split" message you're seeing is definitely harmless and it indicates that Dataflow is trying to further parallelize the work to speed it up, but is already parallelized down to individual records (granted, we should probably make the message less spammy).

Comment: Yes, the pipeline always runs fine with Direct Runner. I'll edit the question, adding code for UnzipAndLoadFn.

Comment: The code looks reasonable. I'm afraid my only remaining suggestion is to add more logging (e.g. at the beginning of UnzipAndLoadFn.processElement() and at each iteration of its while loop) and see what exactly gets stuck.

Comment: Will do. I'll add logger at begging / end of processElement() and while() loop, and see what's going on. Is there a way to somehow filter out "Refused to split GroupingShuffleReader unstarted..." messages using Logs Viewer? tnx.

Comment: @jkff, logging didn't help. I removed resolving input path(s) logic from DoFn. Moved it "outside", to the body of PTransform#apply() and used Create.of() with resulting paths as a start of the pipeline. It' more efficient, since that operation is quick (no need to be executed in ParDo), so there's no longer a need for GroupByKey... hassle. Thanks.